# Cocos-2d actions- make them wait before proceeding to the next line in code?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Basically, say I have this:

```
[sprite runAction:action];
[sprite2 runAction:action2];
```

in cocos2d, this would execute both at the same time. But say i want the first line to fully complete before going onto the next, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the first sprite, run a CCSequence of [action,startSprite2], where startSprite2 is another action (CCCallFunc).  When the 'action' completes, the startSprite2 routine routine will be invoked. Add that to your module, and in that routine start your sprite2 action.

Answer (score 1):

@YvesLeborg answer is correct. There any many other ways of doing this. One way can be like this. Create two functions for each sprite action like

```
-(void)runSprite1Action{
[sprite1 runAction:action];
}

-(void)runSprite2Action{
[sprite2 runAction:action2];
}
```

And then on the parent scene/layer you can add a CCSequence action to that will first invoke the first action and then when first action will finish running , it will invoke the 2nd actions. i.e

```
CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions:[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runSprite1Action)],
                            [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runSprite2Action)], nil];
    [self runAction:sequence];
```

I hope this helps.